# Equivalent symbol not working and subscript on vertical line

Tags: beamer, math-mode, subscripts, delimiters

I have couple of issues here.

I am making a presentation on beamer and I am using the following code:

```
\begin{align*}
    & F_{in} = \int \frac{\partial Q}{\partial s}|_{in} ds, 
              F_{out} = \int \frac{\partial Q}{\partial s}|_{out} ds \\
    & S_{in} \equiv \frac{F_{in}}{Q_{in}}, 
              S_{out} \equiv \frac{F_{out}}{Q_{out}}
\end{align*}
```

However, the result of `\equiv` I am getting is `:=` and I would also appreciate if someone points how to make something like this in LaTeX `|_{out}` to fit with the equation height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  F_\text{in} &= \int \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\frac{\partial Q}{\partial s}\right|_\text{in} ds & 
    F_\text{out} &= \int \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\frac{\partial Q}{\partial s}\right|_\text{out} ds \\
  S_\text{in} &\equiv \frac{F_\text{in}}{Q_\text{in}} & 
    S_\text{out} &\equiv \frac{F_\text{out}}{Q_\text{out}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The extensible `\right|` is used, together with a (blank) `\left.` pair. However, to avoid unnecessary spacing of the empty `\left` delimiter, a negative `\kern` is used.

Since `in` and `out` (most likely) are text components in the set of equations, use [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\text`.

Comment: Everything else is working fine but in my document the `\equiv` function returns `:=`. I don't know what is going on. May be interactions of too many pacakges. Do you have any suggestions to make ? If I use your code its working fine but I don't know what happened in my presentation.

Comment: @Jdbaba: No idea. I'd suggest copying the entire content of your preamble and create a simple minimal document containing a single frame with `$\equiv$` and see what that looks like. If you still obtain `:=` as output, start removing packages until the problem disappears.